# Flutter run error : You have not accepted the license agreements

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-tools

I'm developing android and ios app with Google [flutter](http://flutter.io).
when I add a new dependency like `shared_preferences` to `pubspec.yaml` and then execute `flutter run` in terminal, I got this error:

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences'.
>   You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:   [Android SDK Platform 27].

I know why it happens! because the latest Android SDK platform on my system is 26 . it trys to download sdk 27 and then fails. no problem! I go to library cached folder which located here :

> C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.3.1\android

and edit `build.gradle` file and change `compileSdkVersion 27` to `compileSdkVersion 26`. it works.
so far I have to do this for all new dependencies,
**Is there any way such as defining a global build.gradle file for all dependencies?** so no need to edit each `buil.gradle`s individually.

Comment: http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
check this

Comment: also try to install android studio and run 
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager

Comment: if it still doesnt work, report at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8438

Comment: See this also! (Includes screenshots.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460429/android-studio-installs-without-sdkmanager

Comment: In Android Studio, you should check to ensure that the Android SDK Command-line Tools are installed. Adding this fixed the issue for me in Flutter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67791870/8094969

Answer (score 117):

try these:

1. Open your terminal
2. type `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
3. press `y` to accept every license.

Comment: mine didn't show me anything ... after hours find this solution: If the command line did not show (y/n) please install CMake and NDK or install other versions of Command-line tools

Comment: For CI systems - use `yes | flutter doctor --android-licenses` to avoid the prompt

Comment: @MeirGabay that one actually worked for me, though I don't realy understand why. Isn't this the same as answering the prompt with "y"?

Comment: @Hkrie to be honest, I got to a point where I don’t care as long as it works, took me a few hours to make it run in my CI 

Comment: @MeirGabay, I am also facing the same issue and this command doesn't work for me. it says as 'yes' not recognized. Have you faced any issues like this with the latest android studio version 4.2 and android SDK version 33.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion but it is still taking more than 30 minutes, still waiting....

Answer (score 82):

This worked for me to solve the problem,

1. Open `android studio` (close project if any is opened) >> `Configure` >> `Appearance & Behavior` >> `Android SDK`
2. Go to **SDK Tools** tab
3. Install **Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)**
4. Open `command prompt` software with `run as administrator` and run `yes | flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

[image]

Then open the `command prompt` software and run `flutter doctor`

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. I was about add a post, but I found it here. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS & Android Studio v4.2.1 & Flutter v2.2.0

Comment: Then after installing the Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest), you can now run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accept all of them, one by one.

Comment: This worked for me, using Mac OS X Big Sur. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It helped, I made some progress, I accepted all licenses, but the doctor still says that 5 out of 7 I did not accept.
I followed the procedure with accepting licenses again, rebooted the system and it did not help

Comment: This method Worked!

Comment: Worked like a charm for Mac OS Monterey with Android Bumblebee.

Comment: Thank you. best cmd yes | flutter doctor --android-licenses.

Comment: Not worked for me, taking so long time... waiting for 4 hours... still waiting

Comment: I have opened command line and followed all the suggestions. It worked for me. Thanks dear to save my life :)

Answer (score 37):

I think is a little late to answer this question, but I think this can be useful for those who are starting in Flutter like me.

In my case (at my machine), I've executed the steps below:

1. Execute command prompt **as administrator**.
2. Run the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accept all licenses.
3. Run the command `flutter doctor -v` to check if the issue was solved.
4. To make sure that is everything is ok, execute the command prompt as a regular user (your user) and execute `flutter doctor -v` again.

[image]

Comment: running cmd as administrator was the key point for me. If you dont run as administrator, although i said yes to all, it was still showing that licenses arent accepted

Comment: This answer should be marked as the answer. When I came to the page I scroll down the whole page to find the answer and after that, I tried this and it's working.

Comment: This is the actual answer.

Comment: @Emil, thank you.
Additional info for all: for launch cms as administrator you should.
1. Press "win" button to open the start menu. 
2. Type in the EditText "cmd" to search for Command Prompt.
3. Press ctrl+shift+enter to launch Command Prompt as administrator.

Comment: @Emil right on point. This was exactly it, this should be the first step to resolve this.

Answer (score 32):

For me, `flutter doctor --android-licenses` didn't work for some reason.

The only command that worked & solved the issue was:

`(your android_sdk folder exact path)\tools\bin\sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: I spent 4h for nothing. In the end, just this worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the answer, it worked on my end, upvoted

Answer (score 13):

First make sure Android SDK is installed on your device.
Also see if 2 Android SDK's are not Installed!

Then just simply type on Terminal or CMD `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
Then press `y` until it acquires all permissions.

Comment: Agh, finally. So i's the WINDOWS Command Prompt, not the Visual Studio one. Thank you! All accepted. Yay.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open Android Studio
2. File → Settings → Appearance & Behavior → Android SDK → SDK Tools → Checklist Android SDK Command-line Tools (lastest) → Apply → Download.
   [image]

3. Done.
4. Open cmd and run `yes | flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

Answer (score 7):

If you are in windows open command prompt as admin and run the following command.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Then enter `y` for all (y/n) to accept agreement.

Answer (score 2):

For newer installations (especially on MacOS) flutter `doctor --android-licenses` does not work. Run the following command (notice the new path to sdk cmdline tools) and you will able to accept the licenses:

`~/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

Answer (score 1):

Open Android Studio:

> **File > Settings> Appearance & Behavior> Android SDK> SDK Tools >Checklist Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) → Apply → Download.**

after that run these two commands on your CLI

**flutter doctor --android-licenses**

**flutter doctor (for verifying solution)**

Answer (score 1):

for me, CMD **didn't** show me anything, in prompt, after this command:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

after hours find **this solution**:

> If the command line did not show (y/n) please install CMake and NDK or
> install other versions of Command-line tools

Answer (score 1):

My problem with Windows was that when I ran the flutter command `doctor --android-licenses`, I was using `git for windows`, and the process would hang after selecting the letter `y` and pressing enter. I tried using `CMD` and it worked. I was able to accept the missing licenses.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools-->sdk manager--> install the android OS we have selected for the emulator and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) 26.1.1 worked for me. I found this at another link. I will try to find and pasted here. Remember to un-select show obsolete so you can find the SDK.

After this, I was able to do Flutter doctor Android Licenses and select y.

Answer (score 0):

First you install https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools

Unzip You have a folder like this ...\cmdline-tools
Create name "latest" folder inside cmdline-tools folder and contain other folder then copy into android-sdk path like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbHD2.png)

Update sdkmanager like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm17P.png)

Finally run flutter doctor --android-licenses

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when I reinstalled flutter.

What I did was, I went to Android Studio's welcome page> configuration>SDK Manager>SDK tools>

placed a check mark on →　"Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)"

After that, I was able to run run

`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

and accept the SDK licenses.

It may not work for some but it did for me so I'll just share.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what i did was i installed NDK and CMake Tools in Android Studio. But still doesn't work. So all i did was:

1. Open **Environment Variable**
2. At **System Variable** Box
3. Click **Comspec** and Edit
4. On the **Variable Value**, i paste **C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe**
5. Click OK and open CMD to run **flutter doctor --android-licenses**

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue in `Linux` today and below solution worked for me:

`android-sdk` is saved in `/opt` and the path will be `/opt/android-sdk`.

run `sudo /opt/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`.

and if u run `flutter doctor -v` it will ask for licenses again.

Note: i am using `android cli cmd tools` not `android studio`.

Answer (score 0):

try these for resolve this problem:-

1- Open your cmd from run `win + R`

[image]

2- run this `flutter doctor --android-licenses` in cmd and press Enter key.

[image]

3- press y to accept every license.

[image]

[image]

4- finally All SDK package licenses accepted.

[image]

5- run `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score -1):

```
C:\Users\bansal>flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:

```
D:\android SDK\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

Answer (score -1):

I think is a little late to answer this question, but I think this can be useful for those who are starting in Flutter like me.

In my case (at my machine), I've executed the steps below:

***Before run given command please make sure that you have done with environment variable setup on windows/mac/i/Linux/Unix for***

1. Android SDk
2. sdkmanager
3. Java
4. Flutter

**Note:- update variable path with your sys path**
for example
[image: update variable path]

1. Execute command prompt as administrator; Run the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
2. press `y` to accept every license.;
3. `flutter doctor -v` to check if the issue was solved;

Answer (score -1):

I had `java SE 11` installed and its variables set up.

It somehow **interfered with flutter!**

1. Double-check your java path entry. Go to your java environment variables and double-check your path entry. Keep one of them in the bin and remove the other.

   Mine:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8\bin
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8
   ```
2. In the command line just run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` accept everything (by clicking <kbd>y</kbd> key followed by <kbd>enter</kbd> key).

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me to solve this problem go follow the steps below

1. android studio>>files>>search android sdk>> select SDK tools(TAB)
2. then select android sdk platform tools(uncheck) then click on apply WAIT
3. now go back to SDK tools(TAB) then select  [android sdk platform tools(check)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4aZl.jpg) then click on apply
4. Now run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`in cmd with admin rights
5. click on y and accept all.  Hope the above steps helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I had java 14 and I faced this issue until I did set java 8