# Android Studio installs without sdkmanager

Tags: java, android-studio, flutter, android-sdk-manager

I've been programming in Flutter using macOS 10.15.3, targeting iOS devices. Today I tried installing Android Studio also, to branch out. The installation went without errors, but in `Library/Android/sdk/` there is no `tools` subdirectory, which is a problem because `sdkmanager` is supposed to be found within `Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin`.

I noticed this because running `flutter doctor` gave me:

```
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

I tried reinstalling Android Studio (no difference). Other solutions posted online talk about the Java version, so I upgraded the JRE from 1.7 to 1.8 and tried reinstalling Android Studio (no difference), and then upgraded JDK to the latest (so now the Java version is 11.0.6) and tried installing Android Studio again (no difference). I also upgraded Flutter to v1.12.13+hotfix.8 during the above, but this error won't go away.

If I type `flutter doctor --android-licenses` then I get:

```
    Android sdkmanager tool not found (/Users/macuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager).
    Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
    visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

This is how I first noticed that I'm missing part of Android Studio.

I tried cheating by creating a `tools/bin` subdirectory myself and then copying `sdkmanager` from a plugin's `Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin` to my new `Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin`. However, this didn't fool Flutter. Running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` led to:

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
/Users/macuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

This is wrong because the Android SDK is the newest.

Does anyone know why Android Studio would be consistently missing the `tools/bin` subdirectory and the goodies inside? Thanks and sorry if I overlooked something basic.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Update 1 (2020-02-29)

Seems like latest version of Android SDK renamed the '**Android SDK tools**' package into '**Android-SDK command line tools**'.
But unfortunately current stable version of the Flutter SDK (`v1.12.13+hotfix.8`) is not compatible with this change and it keeps showing error message.

[image: image description]

**Workaround:**

As @Mark Ebden suggested, You can simply Uncheck **Hide Obsolete Packages** checkbox on the **SDK tools** page and you'll see **Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) 26.1.1**. Install it and you are good to go. If you find anything missing, read the following detailed instructions.

See [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51712) issue on flutter repo for more info.

---

Here is the complete details you want while installing android studio with latest version of Mac OS.

**1. Install Android Studio stable version.**

**2. Open android studio**

**3. open SDK manager. See the screen shot below.**

[image]

**4. Make sure you have downloaded all required stuff. See the screenshots below.**

[image]

[image]

Please note that, I am using a custom location (**/Users/darish/development/sdk/android**) for my Android SDK instead of the default location (Library/Android/sdk/)

**5. Go to your home directory and check whether there is a .bash_profile or not. If yes, open it, if no, create one. Add the following contents to that file.**

```
 export PATH="$PATH:~/development/sdk/flutter/bin"
 export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/darish/development/sdk/android"
 export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
```

**6. Once all the above steps are done, run flutter doctor --android-licenses and accept all licenses.**

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

**7. Now run flutter doctor to see everything ok. If you need any further assistance, let me know. :)**

That's all, have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that in step 4, my screen was missing the `Android SDK tools`. Between `Android SDK Platform-Tools` and `Documentation for Android SDK`, there was nothing. Perhaps you have an earlier download than today's `android-studio-ide-192.6241897-mac.dmg`, for version 3.6 dated 12 February 2020.
 **** 
But your screenshot was encouraging. I unchecked `Hide Obsolete Packages` and saw `Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) 26.1.1` appear. I installed this and now everything works.
 **** 
Click for details of the [bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51670) in Flutter.

Comment: Great. Feel free to  accept answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: please clarify how to get the android path ? from where ?

Comment: Android path means android SDK path that we defined in the SDK manager.  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: even after installing obsolete package still getting same error. is there anything else missing.

Comment: Good man. Thank you. I just had to go to tools/SDK Manager in Android Studio, click on SDk Tools, uncheck Hide Obsolete Packages so I can see Andriod Sdk Tools (Obsolete) and check it so it can be installed from there. It will ask you for accepting the licences and that's all.

Comment: In my case, install "Android-SDK command line tools"  in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

1. Run flutter doctor --android-licenses -v
2. I got a message that goes like:

> $ flutter doctor --android-licenses -v Android sdkmanager tool not
>   found (/Users/juarse1/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager). Try
>   re-installing or updating your Android SDK, visit
>   https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
>
> ```
>   throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
>   AndroidLicenseValidator.runLicenseManager (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:311:7)
>   Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:243:38)
> ```

This is because Android SDK is not finding command tools, but this needs to be forced to pull from obsolete package, so:
3. Go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools Section
4. Uncheck Hide Obsolete Packages at the bottom
5. Make sure BOTH options are checked:

> Android SDK Platform-Tools AND Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)

6. OK, close Android Studio
7. Run flutter doctor --android-licenses, should work!

Answer (score 1):

The problems seems to be that in java 11 ( or 9 and 10 ) the jaxb libs are not included in the JDK and android studio sdkmanager can't read the licenses xml files.
You have to include this libs on the classpath (if you are using Java 11), you can follow the instructions posted here (it worked for me in Windows 10)

https://medium.com/@parsher/flutter-android-sdkmanager-update-with-jdk-12-ad8098165472

The last step is not necessary. After included the classpath lines, run de flutter doctor and everything should be all right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 11 or higher, you just you need jaxb libraries which are not included in JDK 11/12 when it runs (especially on Win 10).

Follow the below steps:

1. Download **wget** tool from the location ->
   **https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/**
   and set the environment variable **path** in your computer to run wget command in cmd prompt
2. Locate your Android SDSK\tools folder (<ANDROID_SDSK>\tools) and change directory to it with the cd command: **cd <ANDROID_SDSK>\tools**
3. Execute the below commands inside the **tools** folder:

   mkdir jaxb_lib

   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar -O jaxb_lib/activation.jar

   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.3.2/jaxb-xjc-2.3.2.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-xjc.jar

   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0.1/jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-core.jar

   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-jxc/2.3.2/jaxb-jxc-2.3.2.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-jxc.jar

   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-api.jar

   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.2/jaxb-impl-2.3.2.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-impl.jar

   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.8/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar -O jaxb_lib/istack-commons-runtime.jar
4. Goto the **<ANDROID_SDSK>\tools\bin** folder and edit **sdkmanager.bat** and **avdmanager.bat** files with your favourite text editor (notepad will do).
5. Paste the below code before the statement **‘@rem Execute sdkmanager’** to set classpath.

   set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\jaxb_lib\jaxb-api.jar
   set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\jaxb_lib\jaxb-core.jar
   set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\jaxb_lib\jaxb-impl.jar
   set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\jaxb_lib\jaxb-jxc.jar
   set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\jaxb_lib\jaxb-xjc.jar
   set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\jaxb_lib\activation.jar
   set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\jaxb_lib\istack-commons-runtime.jar
6. Finally execute: <ANDROID_SDSK>\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update

We are all done. Now run **flutter doctor** and now your android license status error should go away. Cheers!!!