# ArgumentError: Invalid argument (URI scheme not allowed): while running the app on web

Tags: flutter-web

```
## flutter doctor

[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.19.0-4.1.pre at D:\fluttersetup\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.9-stable\flutter
    • Framework revision f994b76974 (11 days ago), 2020-06-09 15:53:13 -0700
    • Engine revision 9a28c3bcf4
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-14.1.beta)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Abhishek\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Abhishek\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.61

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Getting this error while running the app on web using flutter-web

Comment: maybe your solution is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460429/android-studio-installs-without-sdkmanager

Comment: okay @Rechem i'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

It might be one of your dependencies which is not yet compatible with Flutter web, try it with a fresh project.

Comment: I already tried to create the new project and paste all the classes even also update all dependencies but getting same error.

Comment: I mean that if a fresh new project can build on web, it's probably one of your dependency in your pubspec.yaml which is posing problems so you should either swap it for a different one, or remove it on your web project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a flutter web app, my mistake was that I moved one of my files to another location inside my project. The IDE (Android Studio) automatically changed the imports that referenced this file with something like this

```
import 'file:///C:Users.............';
```

As you may see the import had an absolute path respect to the file system of my OS (Windows 10)

My solution to fix this was change the import to a path relative to my flutter package

```
import 'package:my_project/src/...........';
```

I hope this may work on your case