# Cannot run program flutter.bat on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-test

I'm running into a problem while creating a flutter project using Android Studio

> Cannot run program "C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat" (in directory
> "G:\test"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file
> specified

[image: error screenshot]

i tried to give full control permissions to the file `C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat`
but still same problem
a screenshot for flutter doctor log
[image: flutter doctor log]

Comment: After the line `Android license status unknown` there a command,did you run that@Yehia Elhawary

Comment: yes, i got error 
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run (C:\Users\Yehia\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager):
"ProcessException: The system cannot find the file specified.
but the file is already exists in the mentioned path

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460429/android-studio-installs-without-sdkmanager @Yehia Elhawary

Comment: I think there is lot problem with flutter using latest android studio update some path issues,plugin fails to load even if it is installed,if this is't work try uninstall and then reinstall android studio  @Yehia Elhawary

Comment: i tried to uninstall android studio, downloaded the latest version of android studion but still same problem, flutter wasn't a strong langauge like i thought

Comment: No flutter is very good,there is something wrong with latest Android studio i think,did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460429/android-studio-installs-without-sdkmanager @Yehia Elhawary

Comment: yes, still same problem
if you have a time, can you join my anydesk ?

Comment: i don't have anydesk brother also i have slow connection@Yehia Elhawary

Answer (score 2):

if you using Avast Antivirus program, its possible that it deleted the flutter.exe file, as it somehow thinks it's IDP.Generic virus ...