# "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception." pops up when trying to run flutter demo app

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get into flutter. Using VS Code and when trying to run the sample app something like this pops up

[image: "the error"]

I have a phone emulator on android studio and it launches but can't find the demo app anywhere

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter run error : You have not accepted the license agreements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements)

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of the error it says:

> Failed to install the following android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.

If you run `flutter doctor` it should also detect this, and offer to help fix them if you run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.