# How to upgrade to Android SDK Version 29.0.3?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I have spent over 5 hours following things from google, GitHub, and StackOverflow.
Still unable to upgrade the Android SDK Version to 29.0.3.

In flutter doctor, it shows the incomplete installation of Android SDK 29.0.3, but when I create a flutter project, it is automatically detecting the old version(28.0.3) and trying to install that, instead of a new version.

Here is the flutter doctor.
[Flutter Doctor Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl8bQ.png)

Here is the flutter run command.
[Flutter Run Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl5Xa.png)

These are Android SDK Manager details:
[Android SDK Manager Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRRUp.png)

Just to mention that I have deleted all folder files of 28.0.3 from the SDK folder, except the licenses file.

Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements

Comment: for my case, I misunderstood from "Flutter requires Android SDK 29 and the Android Build Tools 28.0.3" by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open project at android studio then follow this

- Open 'SDK manager' and 'select android 10.0', and then press OK button
- Find file android > app > build.gradle, and change compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion