# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, dart

I just started flutter online course . I followed every step the instructor did , but when I run the project , I got this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I didn't get any of a thing they said in there , and I m new to stack overflow so please don't mind if my question is bad. Any help is appreciated , thanks!

This is the emulator I used :
[The picture of the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSlTg.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter run error : You have not accepted the license agreements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements)

Comment: run `flutter doctor -v` on your terminal in your project directory, and show us the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the SDK Manager window and accept the license agreements there.