# Flutter:The plugin firebase_auth could not be built due to the issue above

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, sendmessage

I just use firebase_auth package to send me code by phone Number. it work fine in debug mode but when I try to get apk it show me this error. can anyone help me please?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sms:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Mohammad Asef\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\8014592fef965c457f4d96ed4583a915\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\Mohammad Asef\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\8014592fef965c457f4d96ed4583a915\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 52s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     233.5s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the
incompatibility.
Building plugin firebase_auth...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    0.3s

Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)


The plugin firebase_auth could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Answer (score 0):

`firebase_auth` is using AndroidX libraries, but your flutter project is still using the old android support library. To solve this upgrade to flutter latest version. From the docs:

> How do I know if my project is using AndroidX?

Starting from Flutter v1.12.13, new projects created with `flutter create -t <project-type>` use AndroidX by default.

Projects created prior to this Flutter version must not depend on any old build artifact or old Support Library class.

In an app or module project, the file `android/gradle.properties` or `.android/gradle.properties` must contain:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

Comment: mine all is set but still have the same error

Comment: if u execute`flutter doctor` what do you get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements

Comment: but I use SharedPreference too but I don't face to such error in debug mode

Comment: even firebase_auth worked fine in debug mode only get error when I want get apk.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding firebase_analytics dependency in pubspec, then adding manually string value of default_notification_channel_id in android resource just like below

```
<string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">fcm_default_channel</string>
```