# Flutter installation error in windows in cmd

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, brave-browser

[image: Got error in Flutter installation]

Can anyone help me with how I solve these 3 error? I used flutter doctor --android-licenses but It's also not working. Also, I set a brave browser path But got the same error.
I download many SDKs to solve 3 errors but it's also not working.

Comment: For androd licenses run flutter doctor --android-licenses and accept all. If you want to code for web you can install chrome or Edge to test, And look in your Visual Studio how to install these missing components.

Comment: I applied all of those solutions. But still not solve yet. thanks.

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67480249/2831595

Comment: The above solution also not working. I tried my best but not solve it yet.