# Flutter: Some Android licenses not accepted. Cannot accept licenses

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-doctor

I'm unable to accept licenses. When I run `flutter doctor -v`, this is displayed:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/gledyson/bin/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /home/gledyson/bin/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Then I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accept all licenses without an error.

At the end, it says:

```
All SDK package licenses accepted
```

But when I run `flutter doctor -v` again, the warning persists:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/gledyson/bin/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /home/gledyson/bin/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

I have installed the Android SDK and the Command Line Tools (latest) as shown in the pictures:
[android sdk 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPPib.png)
[android sdk 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Nd4.png)

My OS is Linux Mint 20.2.

Comment: Try changing channel then run flutter doctor

Comment: Here are a few options:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements

Comment: I checked the link and found a solution suggesting to run the sdkmanager directly. So I ran it with elevated permissions: sudo ./sdkmanager --licenses. Accepted all licenses again and ran flutter doctor and now it has accepted them correctly.

Comment: since your ask at : /home/gledyson/bin/sdk

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found was to run the sdkmanager directly with elevated permissions using sudo:

```
sudo ./sdkmanager --licenses
```

The sdk file was found under `sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin`.

This solved my issues.

Answer (score 3):

open cmd and run this command
flutter doctor --android-licenses
and accept all.
this worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a Linux Mint user and I had the same problem, but I found the solution

If you install android studio or sdkmanager in the root folder, then when you want to agree to the license, the license agreement will not change because you have to have root authority first.

try running sdkmanager as root then run `sdkmanager --licenses`. if there is a `sdkmanager: command not found` problem, first point $PATH to the directory sdkmanager is in and then run it again as root.

note: don't forget to install cmdline-tools and usually sdkmanager is in cmdline-tools folder.