# run flutter doctor --android-licenses no output and return to shell

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-android

I try to run flutter doctor --android-licenses in windows but no output.And I try to run in administer but with the same result.
Just 2 seconds and it back to shell.
I have installed Android SDK Command-line Tools and it's ok to run Android Studio and package my apps(might means jdk and sdk environment is ok)
So what's the problem here?
[image]
Android Studio:
[image]

If you mean just "flutter doctor -v",it's like this:
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
• Android SDK at E:\Program Files (x86)\Sdk
• Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
• Java binary at: E:\Program Files (x86)\android studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)
X Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
If you mean "flutter doctor -v --android-licenses", still no output.
Pictures: I won't use Visual Stdio,so you can ignore it.
[image]

[image]

change locations:
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
• Android SDK at E:\android\sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
• Java binary at: E:\android\studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)
✗ Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
PS C:\Users\wcyim> flutter doctor -vv --android-licenses
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you include `flutter doctor -v` output[only issue part]?

Comment: It's not beautiful to answer in this, i edited my question so you can see it.

Comment: As the error image describe, you are using `Program File (x86)`, This directory contains space, use another director that does not contain any space

Comment: You mean change Android Studio sdk location to a no space directory? And ``flutter config --android-sdk "no space directory"`` ?

Comment: yes, give a try by changing location.

Comment: Well I changed the location and even uninstall Android Studio to a no space directory,but still no output.New ``flutter doctor -v`` showed in my question

Comment: Do you still get that error after running `flutter doctor --android-licenses ` and after this  flutter doctor shows the same error?

Comment: Yes, I restarted my pc and still no output,and I check --help find I can use -vv to force the log.But I still don't understand why,so I edit my question that shows the -vv result.

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48604914/10157127)

Comment: “mine didn't show me anything ... after hours find this solution: If the command line did not show (y/n) please install CMake and NDK or install other versions of Command-line tools”@saber tabatabaee yazdi 
I install CMake and NDK in Android Studio SDK Tools but still no output

Comment: Better directly add license folder in your sdk