# flutter doctor --android-licenses issue: How to accept android SDK licenses automatically using one liner command in CI systems for flutter APK build?

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, android-sdk-manager, flutter-doctor, android-licenses

We are trying to accept the android SDK licenses for the flutter using the flutter doctor --android-licenses command to accept all the licenses automatically in the CI systems for automation purposes. So, we tried some of the online suggestions and every one-liner command approach for accepting the licenses automatically didn't work. Here's some of the commands we tried at our end.

> echo y | flutter doctor --android-licenses
> [image]

> yes | flutter doctor --android-licenses - this didn't work (reported yes not recognized')

> "yes" | flutter doctor --android-licenses - this didn't work (reported "yes not recognized')

> y | flutter doctor --android-licenses - this didn't work

> "y" | flutter doctor --android-licenses - this didn't work

> echo yes 'y' | flutter doctor --android-licenses
> [image]

The information on the android studio and the android SDK versions are as follows.
[image]
[image]

**Is there any other command line approaches that can be used to accept the android SDK licenses without have to manually press 'y' to accept them?**

Comment: Have you tried `echo y | flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: Yes, I tried that command, but it's not accepting the licenses and ends the command saying that > 7 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)? Terminate batch job (Y/N)?

Comment: What about this: `cmd.exe /C"%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses"`. But ANDROID_HOME should be added to your path

Comment: I have tried this, and it still asks for manual review and accept the licenses. 
`sdkmanager.bat --licenses
7 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)?`. But I need a command that can manually accept the licenses all at once.

Comment: @srk_sync Please try this solution hope it will work for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67480249/12187270

Comment: @Nithin Gadhiya, the cmd line tools is already installed and still that command didn't work

Comment: @srk_sync I found other solution,
~/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

Comment: No, I tried this already and it too asks for reviewing the licenses instead of automatically accepting them.