# How to fix android license unknown error in flutter doctor even after running it on cmd after downloading SDK command-line tools in android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have downloaded the SDK command-line tools in Android Studio from SDK manager and then tried to run 'flutter doctor --android-licenses` in command line prompt in Windows 11. Yet the licenses do not get automatically downloaded and I get the below error in cmd:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZzSk.png)

I also do have an issue in Android Studio as "[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
X Unable to find bundled Java version."
Does this affect it?

And I did try re-installing Android Studio once.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest Android Studio(2022.1.1(Electric Eel))?

There is a change with Java location as the latest Android Studio uses `jbr` and not `jre`.

There are a number of fixes such as https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502

or https://youtu.be/INk__TbhdAE

Comment: Yes I'm using the latest Android Studio (Electric Eel | 2022.1.1)

Comment: I've actually done that and it fixed the error:- "[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1) X Unable to find bundled Java version" but not the other error with android licenses

Comment: Try flutter doctor --android-licenses again otherwise you will have to install the relevant SDK tools in the SDK manager. You can follow these answers for more in-depth assistance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements