# Flutter configuration issue

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsc2F.png)

Please find the attachment of the error. Please help me on this

I have try to setup flutter project with flutter version 1.17.3. In the configuration I am facing some issues. I have installed the following,

Flutter 1.17.3

Android Studio 2023.1.1.26 with SDK 34

Comment: open android studio and in android studio install flutter and dart plugins

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have not accepted the Android License refer the given link to accept the license and also install Command line tools from android studio - [Flutter run error : You have not accepted the license agreements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements)